# Why does glGetProgramInfoLog return an empty string?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm working off a code base that I know compiles correctly. Currently, I've introduced a purposeful spelling mistake into my shader to simulate an error. At this point, the code refuses to compile. I can then call

```
 glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &params);
```

to find that `params` is now 108 where is was previously 0, so I know that there is a log associated with this shader (which I have tried to compile). However, when I call

```
glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, 512, &size, ErrorLog);
```

`size` returns 0, and `ErrorLog` is still empty.

Here's the important code in this situation:

```
void Shader::AddShader(GLuint ShaderProgram, const char* pShaderText, GLenum ShaderType)
{
    GLuint ShaderObj = glCreateShader(ShaderType);
    if (ShaderObj == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating shader type %d\n", ShaderType);
        exit(1);
    }
    const char* pShaderSource = readShaderSource(pShaderText);
    glShaderSource(ShaderObj, 1, (const GLchar**)&pShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(ShaderObj);
    checkCompileError(ShaderObj, ShaderType);
    glAttachShader(ShaderProgram, ShaderObj);
}


bool Shader::checkCompileError(GLuint shader, GLenum ShaderType)
{
    GLint params = -1;
    GLchar ErrorLog[512] = { 0 };
    GLint size = 0;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &params);
    if (GL_TRUE != params) {
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &params);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, 512, &size, ErrorLog);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error compiling shader type %d: '%s'\n", ShaderType, ErrorLog);
        exit(1);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Does [this routine](https://pastebin.com/ux8ppxQX) work on your system?

Comment: Yes, and now I feel silly. The source I've been learning OpenGL from didn't make a big distinction between `glGetShaderInfoLog` and `glGetProgramInfoLog`, and so I thought the latter would work in all cases. Upon seeing your error checking function, and changing to the former, the code works fine. Thanks for your help. If you wanna throw that into an answer I'll accept

Comment: Doh!  Don't feel too bad, I should have seen that too just from reading your code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &params);
glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, 512, &size, ErrorLog);
     ^^^^^^^ should be Shader
```

You're compiling & checking a shader so you should use `glGetShaderInfoLog()`.

`glGetProgramInfoLog()` is for grabbing the link log of the complete shader program object you get from `glCreateProgram()`